Generic class type can't be assigned to a union of types in a for loop in python/pylance/mypy
In pylance/pyright, the following code raises an err:
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from dataclasses import dataclass


class ParentType: ...

class ChildType(ParentType): ...

T = TypeVar("T", bound=ParentType)

@dataclass
class MyClass(Generic[T]):
    a: T

mc1 = MyClass(ParentType())
mc2 = MyClass(ChildType())

def my_func(cls: MyClass[T]) -> T:
    return cls.a

for i in (mc1, mc2):
    my_func(i)
#           ^
# Argument of type "MyClass[ParentType] | MyClass[ChildType]" cannot be assigned to parameter "cls" of type "MyClass[T@my_func]" in function "my_func"
#   Type "MyClass[ParentType] | MyClass[ChildType]" is not assignable to type "MyClass[ParentType]"
#     "MyClass[ChildType]" is not assignable to "MyClass[ParentType]"
#       Type parameter "T@MyClass" is invariant, but "ChildType" is not the same as "ParentType"PylancereportArgumentType
# (variable) i: MyClass[ParentType] | MyClass[ChildType]

The issue is that i above becomes a union of MyClass[ParentType] | MyClass[ChildType], and since my_func expects a MyClass[ParentType], not a union MyClass[ParentType] | MyClass[ChildType], it flags it.
If I don't have the choice of making T covariant, how would you address this issue? Is casting the only option? Should the type checker itself try and account for this scenario?

If you can't change the variance of T in MyClass, you're somewhat out of luck: there's no way mc2 can become MyClass[Parent], it isn't assignable to such type. You need to "reverse" the inference one step further, that usually is done with some sort of upcasting (e.g. mc2: MyClass[ParentType] = MyClass(ChildType()))
